# Deleting pictures with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2007

How do I delete all the pictures in an Excel 2007 worksheet? A working code example would be great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Dim shape As Excel.shape

For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shape.Delete
Next
```

Comment: Note that this deletes PivotCharts (and probably anything else that you select like a picture).

Comment: You are right, to prevent it, assuming that you are using the default chart names ("Chart 1", "Chart 2",...), you can test inside the loop with the inString function e.g. InStr(0,shape.name,"Chart"), so if doesn't contains the "Chart" in the name skip it.

Comment: works not, because it will also delete all comments,buttons... and other stuff wich are also Shapes ! A simple `activesheet.pictures.delete` would do. Or you can use the Loop and add a condition : `if shape.type=msopicture or shape.type=msolinkedpicture or shape.type=msoEmbeddedOLEObject then shape.delete`

Comment: here is a list of all objects considered as Shapes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432678(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 23):

The simplest way:

```
Activesheet.Pictures.Delete
```

or

```
Activesheet.Shapes.Delete
```

Depending on the type of object your picture is.

Deletes all pictures with greater efficiency then iterating (looping through) and deleting them one by one.

Comment: `Activesheet.Shapes.Delete`throws an error (object doesn't support this method)

Answer (score 2):

To delete all pictures or others shapes, you can iterate all of them and check the type:

```
Dim shape As Excel.shape

For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes

    Select Case shape.Type
        Case msoPicture, msoMedia, msoShapeTypeMixed, msoOLEControlObject, msoAutoShape
            shape.Delete
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
    End Select
Next
```

In my case this code was usefull because my sheet was full of transparent shapes of type msoAutoShape which I thought were pictures. So, Activesheet.Pictures.Delete was not working.

You can find all shape types on this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432678(v=office.12).aspx