# Excel shapes errors

Tags: vba, excel

Following the code I found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/17872-how-do-count-how-many-shapes-sheet.html), I'm trying to count the number of shapes in a worksheet, but I'm getting an 'overflow' error. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Sub tst()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes.count
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

The problem, I think is the number of shapes that there are in the worksheet.

I'm not sure how I can delete them either. I tried also deleting the shapes with the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480231/deleting-pictures-with-excel-vba):

```
Sub delShapes()
    Dim shape As Excel.shape
    For Each shape In Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes
        shape.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

But I'm getting also an 'out of range' error.

At this stage, I'm more interested on deleting the shapes as it is making the worksheet un-usable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using a Long type instead of an Integer for your variable i ? Shapes.count return a Long.

Comment: Nice one. It worked with long: 82555 shapes. Any idea on how to iterate through them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try The code below :

```
Sub delShapes()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    i = Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes.Count
    For x = i To 1 Step -1
         Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes(x).Delete
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an out of range here also

Comment: I get an 'out of range' error eve if I try Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes(1).Delete

Comment: You are totally right. The sheet was protected. Removing the protection solved the error. Thanks for this. I spend hours going around this issue.

Comment: I'm glad it helped .. ^^

Answer (score 2):

### Overflow error

In your code you're trying to get the result of `Shapes.Count` into an `Integer`, the problem you're facing is because `Shapes.Count` return a `Long`.

The following code should work as you expect:

```
Sub tst()
    Dim i As Long
    i = Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes.count
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

### Deleting all shapes in your sheet

When you're using a `For Each` loop you do not need to declare the object, you can simply go through all shapes with the following code:

```
Sub delShapes()
    For Each shapeToDelete In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes
        shapeToDelete.Delete
    Next shapeToDelete
End Sub
```

Comment: I still get an 'out of range' error with your delShapes code :-(

Comment: @Selrac What shapes are you trying to delete? And how much?

Comment: at this stage, I would like to delete them all really

Comment: @Selrac Did you try copy-pasting my code? I ran it and everything works. Make sure the name of the sheet is written correctly as specified by arunv.

Comment: "When you're using a For Each loop you do not need to declare the object" - in VBA should always be using "Option Explicit" and the loop variables must also be declared (and is good practice to do so anyway). VB.Net allows a little more leniency, but not VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Over flow issue is explained by Teasel,

to delete the shapes you can use this code

```
Sub delShapes()
Dim shape As shape, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB_AL")
For Each shape In ws.Shapes
    shape.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please verify your sheet name is that "DB_AL" ? or change it

Comment: Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes.count definitely works. I don't think there is a problem with the name "DB_AL"

Comment: Please verify the sheet name in workbook and in code.. both should be same also when you are getting error which line is highlighted?

Comment: when I get the error is on the 'shape.Delete' line. The code runs for a while and then I get the error. The exact error is 'Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The specified error is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

The Overflow error is because the data you are woerking with is *too big* for your variable. You have defined `i As Integer`, but `Sheets("DB_AL").Shapes.count` returns a Long type, and this raises an error. Just define `i As Long` and it will work.

> [**More info about Data
>   Types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary)

To delete all the shapes, try:

```
ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete
```

Comment: Are you sure those are shapes? If none of all answers posted here worked, are you sure you are trying to delete shapes?